# Python how to determine duplicates or no duplicate for all columns

Tags: python, duplicates

I want to output at once to see if column has duplicates or no duplicates on its own. For example:

```
    Student Date            flag
0   Joe     December 2017   4
1   James   January 2018    5
2   Bob     April 2018      6
3   Joe     December 2017   8
4   Jack    February 2018   9
5   Jack    March 2018      1
```

The output should be

```
Column  Dup
Student true
Date    true
flag    false
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Pandas? You should add the tag for it if so.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [Check for duplicate values in Pandas dataframe column](/q/50242968/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should return

```
df.apply(np.unique).apply(len)/df.shape[0] != 1    


Student     True
Date        True
flag       False
dtype: bool
```